# I found an Error at IDEA's debugger

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a class named SNMPv3 as given below. When I try to call the function mergeParameters() from an instance of this class, some strange things occurs.

```
class SNMPv3{
    String[] names={"value1",
                    "value2",
                    "value3",
                    "value4",
                    "value5",
                    "value6"};
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    void mergeParameters(ArrayList<SNMPv3> snmpv3List)
    {
        for(String parametername : this.map.keySet())
        {
            String parametervalue="";
            for(SNMPv3 row : snmpv3List)
            {
                if(!row.equals(this))
                {
                    if(parametervalue.equals(""))
                    {
                        parametervalue = row.map.get(parametername);
                    }
                    else if(parametervalue.equals(row.map.get(parametername)))
                    {
                        this.map.put(parametername, "");
                        for(SNMPv3 rowinside : snmpv3List)
                        {
                            if(!rowinside.equals(this))
                            {
                                this.map.put(parametername,this.map.get(parametername) + rowinside.map.get(parametername));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At compile time when compiler comes into this line when 'row' and 'this' shows same object

```
if(!row.equals(this))
```

it should go to next loop but it does not. Strangely it goes to this line:

```
 this.map.put(parametername,this.map.get(parametername) + rowinside.map.get(parametername));
```

I didnt understand why? Btw I have already checked curly braces.

Then I tried to add an else to that strange if:

```
class SNMPv3{
    String[] names={"value1",
                    "value2",
                    "value3",
                    "value4",
                    "value5",
                    "value6"};
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    void mergeParameters(ArrayList<SNMPv3> snmpv3List)
    {
        for(String parametername : this.map.keySet())
        {
            String parametervalue="";
            for(SNMPv3 row : snmpv3List)
            {
                if(!row.equals(this))
                {
                    if(parametervalue.equals(""))
                    {
                        parametervalue = row.map.get(parametername);
                    }
                    else if(parametervalue.equals(row.map.get(parametername)))
                    {
                        this.map.put(parametername, "");
                        for(SNMPv3 rowinside : snmpv3List)
                        {
                            if(!rowinside.equals(this))
                            {
                                this.map.put(parametername,this.map.get(parametername) + rowinside.map.get(parametername));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Isnt it strange?");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then it works pretty normal. Can someone explain why the hell is this happening?

Comment: Pretty bold statement for a title. You should use the title to describe the problem instead

Comment: "At compile time when compiler comes into this line when 'row' and 'this' shows same object" - at compile-time, `row` doesn't have a value; it's just a variable. Your question is hard to understand because of this. Could you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? (Get rid of anything irrelevant, and make sure we can compile and run it without anything else.)

Comment: That's a lot of messy code for us to debug. Can you provide a smaller example that exhibits this so-called bug?

Comment: You probably haven't implemented the equals()-method for your class, so that of Object is used. That only returns true iff both are the same reference. Without knowledge of how mergeParameters is called (and with what), we can't be certain.

Comment: As a side note: It is almost always a stupid bug in your own code. Quite frequently, a bug in some 3rd party library. Not very often, a bug in standard libraries. Seldom, a bug in the compiler. Extremely rare, a bug in the runtime system. By the way, what is your equals() method?

Answer (score 3):

I think the deal with this line:

```
if (!row.equals(this))
```

Is that you are comparing two objects that have not implemented a equals method, this may cause some strange behaviours.

Override method `equals` from [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) to specify when two "SNMPv3" are [equal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29%20equal).

Comment: The first URL goes 404 on me